# Improved performance with move semantics and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

C++11 has introduced `move semantics` and `rvalue references` to prevent unnecessary copying of temporary objects. My question is, is there any study or paper which shows the improvement `move semantics` have over C++ code not using it.

Some areas where I think it improves performance is in string handling and scientific libraries which use operator overloading. But didn't we already have high performance scientific libraries, such as [blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) that existed even before C++11. Maybe, by the use of `move semantics`, it can be optimized even further.

What do you think, which kind of applications will greatly benefit with `move semantics` and `rvalue references`?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all applications that use the C++ Standard Library will benefit from move semantics without doing anything extra. For instance, take a look at `vector<string>` - move semantics will make the cost of adding new elements and growing the vector dramatically lower.

Comment: Does -std=c++11 flag automatically selects the STL libraries with move semantics?

Comment: According to this page: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 "In this implementation -std=gnu++11 or -std=c++11 flags must be used to enable language and library features"